# generate auto increment order_id in a collection

Tags: mongodb

so I have store collection like following:

```
     { 
         "_id" : ObjectId("5cd4c45492e22458d9570841"), 
         "store_id" : ObjectId("5cd4c45492e22458d9570840"), 
         "create_dt" : ISODate("2019-05-10T00:22:44.000+0000"), 
         "update_dt" : ISODate("2019-06-03T19:35:00.000+0000"), 
         "order_id_counter" : NumberInt(1001)
     }
```

each store has one record which contains a unique store_id, I need to build a function getOrderId(store_id) to automatically return the generated easy to remember unique order_id each time the function is invoked, each call will automatically increase the order_id_counter value by 1 for that store's record(each store will have it's own order_id_counter, it has different value for each store). I also want the operation be atom.

how to write the code for the above function? what's the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to generating a unique, incrementing number in mongo would be creating a separate collection with `{store_id, current_count}` & using a `findAndModify` operations with `$inc` to increment the counter & return the document. In this case, there's no guarantee that once a number is generated that the corresponding order will successfully be created, so you may end up with gaps.

Another approach would be creating a unique index on the combination `{store_id: 1, order_id_counter: 1}` Inserting new orders would sometimes fail and need to be retried.

Answer (score -1):

```
const Autoidmodule= {
    autogenerateId:(request,callback)=>{
        console.log(request)
        var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
        const finalId=request+milliseconds;
        callback(null,finalId)

    },
}
module.exports = Autoidmodule;
...........................................................

let type = "STORE";
let autouserid;
AutogenerateIdcontroller.autogenerateId(type, (err, data) => {
    autouserid = data;
})
```

Comment: This relies on the assumption that Date will always increase (NTP servers can update time & leap seconds are a thing), and that Date is consistent across all servers (clock drift is inevitable & NTP synchronization is limited by network delay), and that two requests can't happen in the same millisecond. Distributed computing is really hard! It's best if possible to use database tools for things like this because they've already worried about these problems

Comment: A quick workaround without handling it in schema level, would be to append n digits random number in finalid.                  const finalId=request+milliseconds+random_number;

Comment: That'd definitely be pretty safe, but at that point, it's basically recreating mongo's ObjectId (4 bytes of timestamp + 5 byte random value + a 3 byte counter starting at a random value). https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/